# How to get selected row index from jquery datatables without using TableTool

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I need to get the row id or index of user selected rows from jquery datatables without using the TableTool.  Once I get the indexes or the Ids, I will use them to select these rows after the user comes back to the same page.  How do I get the row Id or index of the select rows?  Many thanks !

JSP code:

```
 // when a row is selected, I want to get the row id or index
 $('#userTable tbody tr').on('click', function() 
 {
       var oTable = $('#userTable').dataTable();
       var data = oTable.fnGetData(this);
       selectedRowId = data[4]; 
       alert(selectedRowId); // this printed "undefined"

       var rowIndex = oTable.row(this).index();
       alert(rowIndex);  // this alert didn't even get invoked.
  });
```

Comment: If you can provide an example it will be easier to help.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowIndex = oTable.row(this).index();
```

The above will work but you have to use:

```
 var oTable = $('#userTable').DataTable();
```

which will return the API and should allow you to use `row(this).index()`

Instead Of:

```
 var oTable = $('#userTable').dataTable();
```

However without seeing a working copy of the code (JSFiddle maybe) I am unsure why the `fnGetData()` is not working.